# Change background of a div with a slideDown effect when hovering over a link

Tags: jquery, css, hover, slidedown

I am using jquery to change the background of a transparent div when hovering over links in other div (here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/comparebest/yvsK4/)) . Here is the code:

```
$(".trigger2").hover(function (){
    var hoverClass = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".trigger2").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#background").removeClass().addClass(hoverClass);
 },
 function (){  
     $("#background").removeClass().addClass(hoverClass);
 });
```

I want the background-image to change with a slide down effect. I tried to attach `.slideDown()` to different parts of my code but nothing happens.

How should I implement `.slideDown()` to get the deisred effect, and is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- JS --

```
$(".trigger2").hover(function (){
    var hoverClass = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".trigger2").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    //slideDown the background element after updating its class to change the bg image
    $("#background").removeClass().addClass(hoverClass).slideDown(500);
},
function (){  

    //notice you need to get the ID again since the last time was in a different scope not accessible from here
    var hoverClass = $(this).attr('id');

    //start by sliding Up the element
    $("#background").slideUp(500, function () {
         $(this).removeClass().addClass(hoverClass)
     });
});
```

-- CSS --

```
/*Notice I added "display:none", this will allow slideDown to function properly the first time its called*/
#background {
    display:none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:200px;    
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvsK4/2/

Also if you want to use a fade animation you should be able to replace `slideDown`/`slideUp` with `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`.

Comment: this looks almost exactly as i wanted, the only thing I want to change is to avoid using .slideUp. I did a temporary fix by making the slideup speed 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do what you want without using rotating images (rather than css backgrounds), but the [JQuery color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) might be of some use to you.

Look at the examples [here](http://desizntech.info/2009/06/playing-with-jquery-color-plugin-and-color-animation/) (click on Demo), and a [tutorial here](http://desizntech.info/2009/06/playing-with-jquery-color-plugin-and-color-animation/).

Answer (score 0):

The `.slideDown()` function shows the div after it has already been hidden. http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ The slideUp function might be what you're looking for in hiding the div. If you would like to change the image with a slideUp effect, what you can do is put two divs over each other and do a slideUp on the one to be hidden.

I have updated the fiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/yvsK4/1/